# Aligning two tables separated by a line

Tags: tables, xetex

Is there a way to align two tabular elements so that the space between their columns is identically placed, or perhaps insert a non tabular element into a tabular?

Here's the example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size

\begin{document}
\section{Animals and Plants}

\emph{Animals} \\
\begin{tabular}{ll}
My all-time favourites: & gorillas, dogs, horses \\
Other animals: & snakes, frogs, lizards, turtles \\
& squirrels \\
& cats, lions \\
& yaks \\
& eagles \\ 
& various fishes and other marine life \\ 
& many microscopic animals\\
\end{tabular}

\item Fungi are alright\\
\emph{Plants} \\
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    oak & favourite \\
    birch &  alright \\ 
    cactus & good \\
    ivy & hate it\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I want 'favourite' to be aligned with 'many microscopic animals' above it.
Also  I don't know if it makes a difference but I need it XeLaTex compilable.
Thanks.

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a fixed with column:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size

\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\section{Animals and Plants}

\begin{itemize}
\item zzz
\emph{Animals}\strut\\
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{3cm}l}
My all-time favourites: & gorillas, dogs, horses \\
Other animals: & snakes, frogs, lizards, turtles \\
& squirrels \\
& cats, lions \\
& yaks \\
& eagles \\ 
& various fishes and other marine life \\ 
& many microscopic animals\\
\end{tabular}

\item Fungi are alright\\
\emph{Plants}\strut\\
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{3cm}l}
    oak & favourite \\
    birch &  alright \\ 
    cactus & good \\
    ivy & hate it\\
\end{tabular}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: oh, please add a strut next to the`\emph{Animals}` to compensate for lack of descenders.  the vertical spacing without it is awful!

Comment: @barbarabeeton painful image fixed:-)